# Help with MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I create new MVC 3 project in Visual Studio the first thing I do is create a new controller called Home, and then right click in the Index stub and create a new view.

My question is when I have the Index file selected in the solution explorer and build the solution I get an error saying it can't be found. If I navigate to the page using root/ Home or root/Home/Index it still doesn't work.

I also created a new project using the sample website that ships with MVC and cannot figure out what code differs between an empty solution and the sample solution that could be giving me this problem. In the global.asax it looks like there is already a route setup for a home controller so I'm confused.

[image]

Comment: where is the Index file located within your folder structure?  have you made any modifications to global.asax?

Comment: @Robert, I have made no modifications except add a Home controller and a view from the Index stub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller class should be called `HomeController`, not `Home`. On the screenshot you've shown I see that you've called it `Home`. By convention all controller classes in ASP.NET MVC must have the `Controller` suffix. In `Global.asax` you should have a default routing rule which states:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

which means that when you run the site and you request `/` it will look for the `Index` action on the `HomeController`.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce with Microsoft Web Developer 2010 Express, ASP.NET MVC 3 and creating a new empty Razor-view project. When you choose "Add View" did you enable "Create as a partial view"? If so, that may be the issue. Did you enable "Use a layout or master page" and select an existing master page? If not, that may be the issue...

The routing looks fine in an empty project. I see the Home/Index view with these URLs:

- /
- /home
- /home/index

Post problematic project as .zip?

Comment: I didn't choose a master page, but I don't see why this would be an issue. Why would I have to use a master page.

Comment: @nick You're right -- I always seem to be using master pages so I was on auto-pilot. It is working without one. Are you using Debug -> Start Debugging to compile and launch the site? There isn't a lot to go on so sharing the project as a .zip is probably the easiest way to figure out where the error lies.

Comment: how do I post the project file on here? p.s. with debugging it says it cannot find the specified resource, did I type the url correctly. It's going straight to the localhost and port number.

Comment: @nick, you can post it on something like [bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org/).